# Accessing an array with nested objects and displaying keys values

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

I have this data set here: https://gist.github.com/ryancoughlin/8043604 - If you see `tide.tideSummary` it contains an array but inside, it contains multiple dictionaries. I am trying access and display `tide.tideSummary.date.pretty` and display (all 33 of them) in some type of table (but that I have working with dummy data).

I was going through a somewhat similar question here: [Keypath for first element in embedded NSArray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12054846/keypath-for-first-element-in-embedded-nsarray)

Having some trouble finding a solution to access those nested values. Been through plenty of tutorials and posts here on StackOverflow that deal with very basic JSON strings and those work great for me.

---

***UPDATE:***

Came across this question: [Parsing nested JSON objects with JSON Framework for Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2414426/parsing-nested-json-objects-with-json-framework-for-objective-c)

In my case, I have the following:

`NSArray *prettyDate = [[tide objectForKey:@"tideSummary"] valueForKey:@"date"];`

`prettyDate` prints this from `NSLog`

```
Pretty date array: (
        {
        epoch = 1388388109;
        hour = 02;
        mday = 30;
        min = 21;
        mon = 12;
        pretty = "2:21 AM EST on December 30, 2013";
        tzname = "America/New_York";
        year = 2013;
    },
        {
        epoch = 1388397506;
        hour = 04;
        mday = 30;
        min = 58;
        mon = 12;
        pretty = "4:58 AM EST on December 30, 2013";
        tzname = "America/New_York";
        year = 2013;
    },
        {
        epoch = 1388405656;
        hour = 07;
        mday = 30;
        min = 14;
        mon = 12;
        pretty = "7:14 AM EST on December 30, 2013";
        tzname = "America/New_York";
        year = 2013;
    }
```

Then I would be able to loop through each, grab the object and display?

---

Would I do something like:

- Grab parent item `tideSummary` - array
- Grab the item above and store `date` - dictionary
- Access `pretty` via `objectForKey`

I have this `initWithDict`

```
-(id)initWithDict:(NSDictionary *)json {
    self = [super init];

    if(self) {

        NSDictionary *tide = [json valueForKeyPath:@"tide"];

        NSArray *arrOfTideSummaryStats = [json valueForKeyPath:@"tide.tideSummaryStats"];

        NSDictionary *dctOfTideSummaryStats = [arrOfTideSummaryStats objectAtIndex:0];

        NSArray *arrOfTideSummary = [json valueForKeyPath:@"tide.tideSummary"];

        // Loop through the date then...
        // Loop and grab 'pretty'

        // The "first" is the from the example link in my question above. Experimental oonly
        id pretty = [arrOfTideSummary valueForKeyPath: @"@first.tideSummary.date.pretty"];

        // This all works below

        self.maxheight = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [dctOfTideSummaryStats valueForKey: @"maxheight"]];
        self.minheight = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [dctOfTideSummaryStats valueForKey: @"minheight"]];

        /*============================================================*/

        NSArray *arrOfTideInfo = [json valueForKeyPath:@"tide.tideInfo"];
        NSDictionary *dctOfTideInfo = [arrOfTideInfo objectAtIndex:0];

        self.tideSite = [dctOfTideInfo valueForKey:@"tideSite"];
    }

    return self;
}
```

Does anyone have any examples or a direction to steer me in? Would love a resource or question to work off of.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
-(void)parseJson:(id)json{
   NSDictionary *tide = [json objectForKey:@"tide"];
   NSArray *tideSummary = [tide objectForKey:@"tideSummary"];

   for (int i = 0; i < tideSummary.count; i++) {  
      NSDictionary *eachTideSummary = [tideSummary objectAtIndex:i];

      NSDictionary *dateDic = [eachTideSummary objectForKey:@"date"];
      NSDictionary *utcdateDic = [eachTideSummary objectForKey:@"utcdate"];

      NSLog(@"Preety from date dictionary: %@", [dateDic objectForKey:@"pretty"]);
      NSLog(@"Preety from utcdate dictionary: %@", [utcdateDic objectForKey:@"pretty"]);
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I would then call this from my ```initWithDict``` method? Or would I create a different class. The info would be displayed on the same view. I display my others by doing ```self.tideModel.XXX``` and update my label text.

Comment: It depends on your need typically different class is better approach to handle the parsed json. Then you can access easily otherwise have to use valueForKey.

Comment: Thanks again for this, I have it displaying. I want to display several parts of this. How would I bind this to a model so I can do: ```tide.data.type``` or ```tide.date.pretty``` - I looked in to JSONModel, but that takes arrays, I have nested objects. Thoughts? Or a pointer in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at [Initialize NSArray with data from NSdictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20772126/initialize-nsarray-with-data-from-nsdictionary/20773215#20773215) as I have already answered this
 Hope this helps.

Comment: Oh great, thanks @Vish - very similar question with an answer.

Comment: Ok. If you are able to solve your problem mark this answer solved. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding what you are trying to do, you should be able to replace this part:

```
// Loop through the date then...
// Loop and grab 'pretty'
```

with something like:

```
for (NSDictionary *tideSummary in arrOfTideSummary) {
    NSDictionary *date = [tideSummary valueForKey:@"date"];
    NSLog(@"Pretty date: %@", [date valueForKey:@"pretty"]);
}
```

If you want the date values in a table of some sort, then you could store them into a new array or some other data structure and then create a table view that uses that as its data source.

Answer (score 0):

I have below data on JSON link...

```
{
"results":[
    {
        "address_components": [
            {
                "long_name": "Satadhar",
                "short_name": "Satadhar",
                "types":[
                    "point_of_interest",
                    "establishment"
                ]
            } ]
]
```

I fetched data through `ASIHTTPREQUEST` so the code is below given

```
-(void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request {
        NSError *err;
        NSData *data=[request responseData];
        NSDictionary *dict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data   options:kNilOptions error:&err];

        arr=[[dict valueForKey:@"results"]valueForKey:@"address_components"]; //to fetch the data till inside Starting point i.e address_component

        _arrTable=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init]; //take a array to store the data of the index 0 [index 0 store the whole data that is start from [array] ]

        _arrTable =[arr objectAtIndex:0]; //get the data of 0th index

        NSLog(@" whole data%@",_arrTable);//print it u will get the idea

        NSLog(@" my %@",[[arr objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"long_name"]);
        NSLog(@" my %@",[[arr objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"short_name"]);

        [self.tblview reloadData];
    }
```